# Generating a fancybox frame from a leaflet popup

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, cloudmade

I am trying to have a popup generated with leaflet hold an anchor tag which when clicked opens the webpage in fancybox window. This works just fine outside of the popup content when generating a fancybox using

```
<a class='fancybox.iframe' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Needle'>More Info</a>"
```

but when I put that in the leaflet popup the fancybox doesn't doesn't work and it just opens in a new window.

```
var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(47.6204, -122.3491),
marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
map.addLayer(marker);
var popupContent = "<a class='fancy fancybox.iframe' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Needle'>More Info</a>";
marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
map.on('click', onMapClick);
var popup = new L.Popup();
```

I'm fairly new to all this so how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

hope you use the v2

it would help if you show your code where you bind your link to fancybox plugin 
something like :

```
$(function(){
   $(".fancy").fancybox();
});
```

maybe you would need to call this binding after you add your link !

A second option would be to call the fancybox plugin directly on the onclick of the link
something like :

```
<a href="..." class="fancybox.iframe" onclick="$.fancybox(this);return false;">More info</a>
```

Comment: Perfect the second option worked great. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding the fancybox on `$(document).ready()` or something similar? If so, it looks like your popup content doesn't exist within the DOM at that time. It needs to exist in order to have a click event bound to it.

If your map triggers an event that you can attach a callback to when the popup opens (when the content gets added to the DOM), then you can bind the fancybox click at that time. It looks like your `onMapClick` function might do the trick, if that's where it adds the popup content to the DOM. If so, add your `$('whatever').fancybox();` at the end of it.

In the worst case scenario, you could try adding a `<script>` tag after the `<a>` within `var popupContent`, in which you call the fancybox binding.